# Word2vec - get rank of similarity

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, gensim, word2vec

Given I got a word2vec model (by gensim), I want to get the rank similarity between to words.
For example, let's say I have the word "desk" and the most similar words to "desk" are:

> 1. table 0.64
> 2. chair 0.61
> 3. book 0.59
> 4. pencil 0.52

I want to create a function such that:

> f(desk,book) = 3
>   Since book is the 3rd most similar word to desk.
>   Does it exists? what is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `rank(entity1, entity2)` to get the distance - same as the index.

```
model.wv.rank(sample_word, most_similar_word)
```

---

A separate function as given below won't be necessary here. Keeping it for information sake.

Assuming you have the list of words and their vectors in a list of tuples, returned by `model.wv.most_similar(sample_word)` as shown

```
[('table', 0.64), ('chair', 0.61), ('book', 0.59), ('pencil', 0.52)]
```

The following function accepts the sample word and the most similar word as params, and returns the index or rank (eg. [2]) if it's present in the output

```
def rank_of_most_similar_word(sample_word, most_similar_word):
    l = model.wv.most_similar(sample_word)
    return [x+1 for x, y in enumerate(l) if y[0] == most_similar_word]

sample_word = 'desk'
most_similar_word = 'book'
rank_of_most_similar_word(sample_word, most_similar_word)
```

Note: use `topn=x` to get the top x most similar words while using `model.wv.most_similar()`, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: The call to `most_similar` probably has to include `topn=len(model.wv.vocab)`, otherwise `most_similar_word` will not be found in the list and you'll get back an empty list